# Segfault in shared library. How to debug?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

I use a library (libnids) in my program. I call the function nids_run from the library which continues running until I explicitly call nids_exit.

My program handles SIGINT and calls nids_exit. The interrupt handler returns normally, but sometimes before the library returns the control to my program, I receive a segfault. This is the backtrace GDB gives me:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6498b2a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1
#1  0x00007ffff649bee1 in pcap_loop () from /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff77bae66 in nids_run () from /usr/lib/libnids.so.1.24
#3  0x0000000000401e92 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffebf8) at eve.c:139
```

What is the best strategy to find the problem? Should I somehow debug libpcap?

**UPDATE:**
As suggetsed by ArjunShankar, I ran my program under Valgrind. This is part of the output:

```
==7504== Invalid read of size 4
==7504==    at 0x654EDC1: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1.2.1)
==7504==    by 0x6551EE0: pcap_loop (in /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1.2.1)
==7504==    by 0x5250E65: nids_run (in /usr/lib/libnids.so.1.24)
==7504==    by 0x401E91: main (eve.c:139)
==7504==  Address 0x70eece8 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 768 free'd
==7504==    at 0x4C29A9E: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7504==    by 0x5250DEB: nids_exit (in /usr/lib/libnids.so.1.24)
==7504==    by 0x4026D0: signal_handler (signalhandling.c:17)
==7504==    by 0x5B6313F: ??? (in /lib/libpthread-2.15.so)
==7504==    by 0x5B5FC60: pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (in /lib/libpthread-2.15.so)
==7504==    by 0x58E37D4: g_cond_wait_until (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.1)
==7504==    by 0x587E2C0: ??? (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.1)
==7504==    by 0x587E909: g_async_queue_timeout_pop (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.1)
==7504==    by 0x4022D2: analyzer_thread_func (analyzers.c:93)
==7504==    by 0x58CA0C4: ??? (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.1)
==7504==    by 0x5B5BE0D: start_thread (in /lib/libpthread-2.15.so)
```

More of the output can be found at: http://pastebin.com/93gkSScS

Comment: Try [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Comment: The bug need not be in libpcap (and probably isn't -- `select` ain't broken and all that). If your program happens to stomp on memory used by the library, this could be the result.

Comment: I never really suspected libpcap itself. The problem is, how do I find out what I did wrong that caused the problem.

@ArjunShankar I've never used valgrind before, but this part of its output might be relevant: http://pastebin.com/93gkSScS

Comment: @Homayoon - I think you should paste some of the valgrind output into your question. It seems pretty pertinent. And there is no guarantee that pastebin.com will forever be running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Valgrind output shows that `libpcap` (from inside `nids_run`) tries to read memory locations after `nids_exit` `free`s them:

e.g.:

```
==7504== Invalid read of size 4
==7504==    at 0x654EDC1: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1.2.1)
==7504==    by 0x6551EE0: pcap_loop (in /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1.2.1)
==7504==    by 0x5250E65: nids_run (in /usr/lib/libnids.so.1.24)

Address 0x70eece8 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 768 free'd
==7504==    at 0x4C29A9E: free
==7504==    by 0x5250DEB: nids_exit (in /usr/lib/libnids.so.1.24)
```

So that is a 768 sized block, that is `free`d in `nids_exit`, and subsequently read inside `nids_run` (which apparently has not stopped yet).

All other errors are similar (`nids_exit` `free`s a block, and `nids_run` continues to try to use it.

What this means is: You're either not using libnids (`nids_run`/`nids_exit`) correctly, or there is a bug in `libnids`.

Comment: It does seem to be a bug in libnids. I've created a patch that seems to fix the problem. I'm waiting for the author to comment, before marking this as the answer, although I'm quite sure this is the right answer in any case (unless someone comes up with something even more complete). Thank you.

Comment: @Homayoon - For the sake of curiosity, would you share a link to the patch? I downloaded the source of libnids, but haven't looked at it yet.

Comment: Sure. Here it is: http://pastebin.com/GVrUbRmh. I'm not quite sure if this is the right thing to do, although it appears to fix my problem. Even if it is correct, there's probably a bit more to do to make things completely right, but I'll leave that to the author. I've been using libnids for a month or two now, and, ignoring this problem, it seems to be a good piece of code.